# Run animation sequentially for infinite time

Tags: android, android-xml, android-animation

How do I define a set of animations without using the `<set>` tag? I read somewhere on this forum that the set tag has a buggy implementation and will not run with `repeatCount="infinite"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override `onAnimationStart` and `onAnimationEnd`, if you you extend `View`, to trigger starting the new animation when the old animation has finished.

Comment: WIll that have to be a separate class that extends animation?

Comment: no it will be a separate class that extends View.  the animation can be constructed without extending `Animation`.